# View log from a web page

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am working on an application and part of it is having an administration panel where different configuration options can be edited on the fly. This is not a problem and can be easily achieved.

However, there is one functionality that I don't know how to implement and would be a nice feature to have. The possibility to view the application log from this admin panel. Something similar to what the Activator UI has where it displays messages from Logger.info/Logger.debug/etc.

One solution would be to send the log as a String array and have it displayed, however I would like to achieve something that displays it continuously, without the need to refresh the page (again, similar to the Activator UI).

Any suggestions or links to documentation I might have missed are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am seeing this as a trivial task (correct me if I am missing some requirement) - but it should be relative easy to implement and should go like this:

- Use a `Logger` to log message during application lifecycle
- The log is stored in `<yourproject>/logs/application.log` (default)
- Define some reader - the implementation is up to you - you can use bare `FileInputStream`, you can have a special Akka actor handling this, you can use some library or whatever you imagine
- Display the result of the file reading procedure in the admin area

---

**Edit:** Possible implementation (regarding the OP's comment):

- Use Akka for the task. Create an Actor which is handling the reading of the log file.
- In Akka you can schedule messages which are going to be send to an actor. Every time your actor gets a message, he reads the log file - you can make this interval configurable (think `application.conf`)
- Now enhance your application by adding WebSocket capability. The good thing is that you can implement the actor so that it handles the WebSocket connection and thus "writes" to the WebSocket channel. This way you are going to receive data on the client side only when it was read on the server side.

Note 1: this is all for sake of simplicity. In reality you would probably use (at least) two actors - one for handling the WS connection and one for the File Log IO operations.

Note 2: you can of course try SSE. But I find WS not harder and you get the benefit of having a two-way connection.

---

Comment: The web-view is rendered on the client side. This will indeed work and is easy to achieve (like I mentioned in my comment) but once the page has rendered in the browser the log will not update. An option is to do a refresh or an AJAX call to fetch the new data and repopulate the view, however, this may put pressure on the service if the log is requested too often.

Comment: I updated my answer with some more information - a possible implementation where the server decides when to send the data. Please also keep in mind that you will always have this trade-off - either you read the log often and put pressure on the service or you read it e.g. every two minutes - depends on how critical the log info is for your use case

Comment: Thanks. Never worked with Akka, but reading what it does it may be a good solution for what I need. This way I can then read the input stream from the websocked on the client side and have it displayed. Will look more into this solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I think this answer can be implemented even without using Akka. Also never worked with Akka.

Comment: Of course it can be done without using Akka. I just find the use case suitable and given the tight connection between Play and Akka, I see it as an option. However if one is not familiar with Akka and needs a simple 30-min solution, you are right.